# Отладка release версии сборки проекта

Tags: c++, linux, отладка, gdb

Всех приветствую. Я пишу обертку над сишной библиотекой libgphoto2. Программа компилируется на одноплатнике, работающем под линуксом, к нему подключаюсь по ssh с отдельного компьютера и работаю с ним через vs code. Возникла проблема с внезапным segmentation fault, который проявляется лишь в release сборке проекта, debug работает так, как и рассчитано. Накатил gdbserver в надежде дойти до того места, где программа падает, но точки останова просто не работают в релизной сборке. Понимаю, что где-то перемудрил с указателями, но точное место никак не могу найти. В связи с этим у меня вопрос - как в таких случаях можно поступить, как отлаживать программу, если релизная сборка может просто выкинуть половину кода, а отладчик не запускается? Может есть еще какие то варианты увидеть "место" падения, посмотреть какой нибудь расширенный вызов методов/функций/и прочего? std::cout не помогает к сожалению, ошибка появляется тогда, когда программа дергает сишную api для работы с фотиком и внутри себя освобождает память, какую - не знаю, так как я явно ее не выделяю в принципе.

Comment: Взять эмулятор и пройтись по релизу пошагово? :)

Comment: Релиз бывает с отладочной информацией. Из-за оптимизаций будет трудно ходить по шагам в отладчике, но это преодолимо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а можете пожалуйста поподробнее описать сей процесс. Возможно, я что-то делаю неправильно, так как у меня в релизной сборке в принципе точки останова не работают никакие, не думаю, что там весь код компилятор "оптимизировал". Я стартую gdbserver из папки с проектом, к этому проекту я подключен через плагин для vs code по ssh, и в этой же папке с проектом у меня есть json, который описывает подключение к "target" через расширение "native debug".

Comment: С другой стороны, я слабо себе представляю, как это работает :) Физически проект находится на плате, я с ним работаю по ssh, и в этой же папке, лежащей на железке, я и стартую сервер gdb, и описываю json, который подключается к серверу. На странность, у меня это работает) Я читал мануалы, и плюс минус понимаю принцип работы, когда на целевом устройстве сервер стартуется, а подключается из под того, на котором работаешь, но без расширения для vs code очень неудобно прописывать команды отладчика прям из gdb консоли хоста.

Comment: В debug вы отлаживаться на плате можете? Точки останова работают? Если да, то надо в release добавить отладочную информацию и запуститься точно также как в debug.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что это ключ "-g" для компилятора в cmake? Попробовал, все равно не работает

Comment: а просто запустить под gdb и после сегфолта получить bt не поможет?